# Writing secure transport level using security framework

Tags: ios, cryptography, transport-security, security-framework

I have developed security sensitive App. I had to use [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) based algorithm to encrypt/decrypt data to communicate with server and follow Server protocols. I have used [AsyncSocket](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AsyncSocket) for trasport level communication which uses `CFNetwork` APIs. I have noticed that `TEA` algorithm is not very secure and can be hacked easily. Moreover, `AsyncSocket` library isn't using Apple's [Security Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html) anywhere. I am planning to rewrite transport layer and redefining client-server security protocols. I have been researching on what kind of security algorithm should I use for data protection which has no or minimum performance impact and difficult to break. Moreover, I am going through Security frameworks but couldn't find any example that uses this framework to implement transport layer. Could someone please assist me on this? What are the things I should follow to code secure transport layer? *what are the security measures that I could check against my App?*

Comment: Secure against **what**?

Comment: How about just using SSL/TLS? It's certainly much better than anything you'll come up with.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for pointing this out. I was totally missed term data protection! I want to ensure the communication between my app and server to be A grade secured! Data exchange between app. I am using TEA which uses key hard coded in App to encrypt data and the same key uses on server side which isn't seem to be very robust solution!

Comment: @CodesInChaos Based on this -http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs/SecureNetworkCommunicationAPIs.html , CFNetwork already uses SSL/TLS. Does that mean my App is already secured enough?

Comment: @AppleDeveloper: Again: Communication secured against **what** (and, more importantly, who)?

Comment: @SLaks I apologise if I am missing something but security would be always against preventing bad things happenings! Isn't it? To make sure nobody could hack your data and attack server with bad data etc.. It would be also helpful for me if you can list out security measures that I need to check against my App. I am still in somewhere middle to decide what could be the best approach to handle data protection and preventing bad things happening, and what are the security measures etc...

Comment: What @SLaks is trying to say is that your question is similar to "I have purchased a deadbolt lock. Is my building safe?" It depends on how you install the deadbolt, what kind of building, who is likely to try to break into it, and many other things. In no case will a deadbolt protect you against a fire ("a bad thing happening"). Security is a collection of overlapping processes, people, and tools that manage risks. It is a not a product that you install and are "safe." No one can tell you in a SO post whether you have adequately addressed all relevant attacks. That requires an assessment.

Comment: @RobNapier that's beautiful explanation. Thank you.

Comment: wow Rob! that's beautiful explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CodesInChaos notes, you should use TLS for this. You absolutely should not design or implement a new transport protocol.

The fact that CFNetwork supports TLS does not mean that you are using it. You need to actively use it. Your server needs a certificate that your client trusts, and it needs to negotiate a TLS session. In general, if you just use HTTPS and the standard `NSURLConnection` routines , then you're going to get most of what you need for free. But if you start building it by hand in `CFNetwork`, you need to make sure that you're configuring it correctly. My recommendation is to use HTTPS whenever possible. It's simple and makes a wide variety of problems go away.

That said, just because the transport is secured does not mean that your app is "secured enough." In particular, your server still needs to be able to deal with malicious clients talking over a secured transport. You need to properly authenticate the user and you need to handle malicious data gracefully. When the data reaches your server, you need to store is securely. You may need to encrypt data on the client. There are many aspects to securing a system beyond the transport.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. +1 for "You need to actively use it." - the code already been written ages ago and we are neither using HTTPS nor TLS certificate. App uses HTTP URL connection for non-critical data which I am not worried about. It uses AsyncSocket library to communicate with server using CFNetwork TCP Sockets(IP and port given). No where it uses TLS. Just before writing sensitive data on socket using CFStreams, we just use TEA to encrypt them as I mentioned. Could you suggest our implementation is insure? Should I use TLS? Are there any other security measures I should check?

Comment: You should almost certainly use TLS. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of other security measures you could implement. Without detailed information about your specific product, access to your designs and implementations, there's no way to answer this question. But as a start, yes, you should almost certainly use TLS with certificate validation. Note that using HTTP for "non-critical" data can still create significant security holes. For instance, there may be attacks by tricking you into accepting instructions from the wrong server. It depends on your specific protocol and project.

Comment: Thank you Rob. I would need to look more into our security measures requirements. Data protection and identifying source of data would be solved using good encryption algorithm and TLS respectively.